# How to share a queryset between SerializerMethodFields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that I use to display details about how a team is performing in a sports league..

```
class TeamLeagueSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = [...]
    games_played = fields.SerializerMethodField()
    games_won = fields.SerializerMethodField()
    games_lost = fields.SerializerMethodField()
    points_for = fields.SerializerMethodField()
    ...etc...

    def fixtures(self, team):
        # Retrieves all relevant fixtures for a given season and a given team
        return Fixture.objects.filter(Q(home_team=team) | Q(away_team=team),  season=self.season)

    def get_games_won(self, obj):
        home_results = Q(home_team=obj, result__home_team_score__gt=F('result__away_team_score'))
        away_results = Q(away_team=obj, result__away_team_score__gt=F('result__home_team_score'))
        results = self.fixtures(obj).filter(home_results | away_results)
        return results.count()

    def get_games_lost(self, obj):
        home_results = Q(home_team=obj, result__home_team_score__lt=F('result__away_team_score'))
        away_results = Q(away_team=obj, result__away_team_score__lt=F('result__home_team_score'))
        results = self.fixtures(obj).filter(home_results | away_results)
        return results.count()
```

This all works correctly, but for a league of 8 teams, this can take around 5 seconds to complete since each `SerializerMethodField` is a separate query being done..

My non-api version of this code is much more simple with a single queryset that annotates each property that this serializer is trying to create, rather than individual queries.

So for the given serializer, is it possible to do the same thing and construct a serializers data from a single query instead of multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom query at the ViewSet level by setting the `queryset` attribute or overriding `get_queryset`.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself

That query could potentially be the same one that you use in the non-api version.

The result of that method will feed the Serializer directly, so every extra annotations will be available there. You may need to define your annotated fields in the Serializer with a `read_only=True` flag.

Comment: Oh of course! I have seriously been overly complicating this by trying to only use what was available on a serializer rather than the viewset... Ill try this out later and accept this accordingly....

Answer (score 1):

Couple of possible solutions:

1) Group them together into one field

```
class TeamLeagueSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = [...]
    details = fields.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_details(self, team):
        #your non-api version of the code
        return {games_played: fixtures, games_won: won, games_lost: lost}
```

2) Or if you really want to keep the API the same, another possibility is to set each of the attributes as properties on the model, and have an additional cached property for example self._team_info to store the result of the query for future use:

```
class Team(models.Model):
     #your fields

    @property
    def team_info(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_team_info"):
               #Your non-api version of the code
               self._team_info = #result of your query containing fixture info, games won, games lost, etc, .e.g. in a dictionary
        return self._team_info

    @property
    def fixtures(self):
        return self.team_info['fixtures']

    @property
    def games_won(self):
        return self.team_info['games_won']

    @property
    def games_lost(self):
        return self.team_info['games_won']
```

Then in the serializer you don't need to set any SerializerMethodFields, you can just refer to games_won, games_lost and fixtures in your fields attribute:

```
class TeamLeagueSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = [..., 'fixtures', 'games_won', 'games_lost']
```

Comment: option 1 might have to be with what I go with but the stand out issue would seem to be that this then means to use these values it becomes `instance.details.games_played` which I'm not sure if that is a very good solution... I'd rather not dilute my model with api specific code though so I don't see 2 as a viable option for me